# Discord.js ReferenceError: bot is not defined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to create a bot, which will be given the role when user joins the server by link, but this doesn't work. 
Error:

```
C:\DGhostsBot\bot.js:45
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
^

ReferenceError: bot is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\DGhostsBot\bot.js:45:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

My code here:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

var prefix = "dg!"

client.login(`**************************************************************`);

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.content == prefix + "test") {
        message.reply("just a command that is used for performance testing. Do not pay attention.");
     }
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.content == prefix + "cake") {
        message.reply("here's your cake :3 :cake: ");
     }
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.content == prefix + "help") {
        message.reply("it's in development");
}     
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.content == prefix + "kick") {
if(message.member.roles.some(r=>["Developer", "devadmin"].includes(r.name)) ) {
     const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (user) {
      const member = message.guild.member(user);
      if (member) {
       member.kick()
}
}
} else {
 message.reply("!!!!ACCESS_DENIED!!!!").then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete("delete"));

}
}     
});


bot.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {

    if (member.id == bot.user.id) {
        return;
    }
    let guild = member.guild
    guild.fetchInvites().then(invdat => {
        invdat.forEach((invite, key, map) => {
            console.log(invite.code)
            if (invite.code === "qQAkqFQ") {
                return member.addRole(member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Member"));
            }
        })
    })
});
```

I check a lot of answers on the internet, but nothing of all this doesn't work.
So, I do not know how to fix this error.

Comment: It's quite simple, you've never declared a variable called bot. Instead you have a variable called `client`. The fix: change `bot.on(...)` to `client.on(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `bot` use `client` like you did all the times before.

There are people who do `const client = new Discord.Client();` but there are also people who name it `bot` or even something really weired.

If you want to learn how to make your own bot, you can use the open-source guide created by the members and creators of `discord.js` wich can be found here: https://discordjs.guide/

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `bot.on(...)` to `client.on(...)`

You didn't define `bot` in previous code, so you can't use it. You defined your Discord client as `client` in the following line:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

That's why you have to use client. You can't create a listenener for a non existing client.

For further details about all events of Discord.js, you can have a look at the official discord.js documentation: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client

There you can also find all details on how to listen to events etc.